# Gerar array em JSON pelo PHP

Tags: php, json

Eu estou estudando uma forma de enviar um resposta JSON do PHP para o JS. Eu olhei diversos posts aqui e em outros fórums, mas não consigo encontrar o meu erro.

Eu faço um SELECT de tudo em uma tabela do MySQL através do PHP, mas quando envio ao JS e vejo a resposta no console, apenas um resultado é mostrado, o primeiro, não os demais.

Provavelmente há algo errado no meu PHP, pois o JS apenas mostra o resultado no console.

No código tem um trecho assim:

```
($result->num_rows > 5)
```

Esse trecho é proposital, pois queria testar se receberia um resultado igualmente, sei que o correto é testar se é > 0.

**Código PHP:**

```
    public function selectTable(){
     $return_arr = array();

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM coletas";
     $result = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 5) {
       while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $codigo_intervencao = $r['codigo_intervencao'];
          $sql2 = "SELECT intervencao FROM intervencoes WHERE id = $codigo_intervencao";
          $intervencao = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $sql2);
          $intervencao2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($intervencao);
          $return_arr['codigo_intervencao'] = $intervencao2['intervencao'];
          $return_arr['tempo'] = $r['tempo'];
       }
     }
     return json_encode($return_arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
   }
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc obsoleto...

Comment: @VictorGomes [Hein?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só está recebendo um resultado pois você está sobrescrevendo os demais, com o código abaixo:

```
$return_arr['codigo_intervencao'] = $intervencao2['intervencao'];
$return_arr['tempo'] = $r['tempo'];
```

Para retornar todos, é necessário criar um [*array multidimensional*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php#example-85). Exemplo:

```
$return_arr[]['codigo_intervencao'] = $intervencao2['intervencao'];
$return_arr[]['tempo'] = $r['tempo'];
```

Dessa forma você conseguirá armazenar todos os valores para exibi-los posteriormente.

Comment: Great, it works.